# How can I keep alive client openfire?

Tags: ionic-framework, xmpp, openfire

I creating a messenger program using XMPP & openfire.

I have a problem. When I login to messenger and do not anything my phone.

Openfire did disconnect my ID.

This is openfire INFO logs.

org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpSessionManager - Closing idle session: test2@domain/PM

I already set

Do not disconnect clients that are idle.

from openfire admin pages. Server -> server settings -> Client Connections -> Idle Connections Policy tab

What's wrong?

Comment: On client side did you observe ping messages from Server? After how long the client has been disconnected?

Comment: Thanks for reply beaver :) I'm not sure disconnected time. Becuz it's irregular time when I login my app. So..I trying many test now..

Comment: I found it's log. 2016.04.06 14:42:41 WARN  [Jetty-QTP-BOSH-310]: org.jivesoftware.openfire.http.HttpSession - Deliverable unavailable for 2057000648. This log be created after when I take an elevator. maybe network reconnect after got off an elevator. how can I fix it?